# How to dispose multi page editor view when Eclipse close?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I have created a mulipage editor plugin and it works fine. The problem is after closing the eclipse and opening it again. I am getting an error like failed to create parts control.

Because the eclipse session holds the opened file in the editor. So, I would like to close all the multipage editor instance opened in the Eclipse while the Eclipse session is closing.

I want to dispose the editor tabs during Eclipse close.

Any advice?

Comment: If your editor is written correctly it should not have a problem with being opened as Eclipse starts.

Comment: @greg-449 : I editor uses some data from the selected file. But I am not persisiting the data after the eclipse session close.But after opening the eclipse ,the editor will be there.So it needs data. Which is not available.

Comment: So, I need to close the editor tabs while the eclipse session ends,is it possible to so that?

Comment: If this is your RCP with your own WorkbenchAdvisor you can use the WorkbenchAdvisor preShutdown method.

Comment: If it is your editor implementation just override the editor's dispose() method and add the necessary cleanup code. The dispose() method will be called by Eclipse when shutting down.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IWorkbenchListener` to listen for the workbench being shutdown You could close your editors in the `preShutdown` method:

```java
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().addWorkbenchListener(new IWorkbenchListener()
 {
   @Override
   public boolean preShutdown(IWorkbench workbench, boolean forced)
   {
     // TODO close editors
     return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void postShutdown(IWorkbench workbench)
   {
   }
 });
```

Comment: That's a bad idea. An editor must solve that issue by itself, since the editor can be installed into other applications where this workbench listener doesn't exist. Therefore overriding dispose() at the editor, or modifying the EditorInput for this specific editor seems more useful to me.

Comment: @Bananeweizen I told the OP that in the comments 3 years ago